# How can I make sure custom XNA content processors find included files with relative paths?

Tags: xna, xna-content-pipeline

MSDN has [an example of a custom HLSL effect importer and processor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447754.aspx#ID4EWG). Here is the importer's code:

```
public override PSSourceCode Import(string filename, 
    ContentImporterContext context)
{
    string sourceCode = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename);
    return new PSSourceCode(sourceCode, System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename));
}
```

In the processor they do this:

```
    EffectContent effectSource = new EffectContent();
    effectSource.EffectCode = input.SourceCode;
    EffectProcessor processor = new EffectProcessor();
    compiledEffect = processor.Process(effectSource, context);
```

The sample works okay, however, when you try to import and process an effect file that has `#include "otherEffect.fx"` directive in it, the build process throws an error "Failed to open source file 'otherEffect.fx'". I presume that is because the relative path of the file is not specified correctly but I don't know where to specify it. Does anyne know this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those having the same trouble, you should add two lines in the processor:

```
EffectContent effectSource = new EffectContent();
effectSource.EffectCode = input.SourceCode;
//Add these two lines:
effectSource.Identity = new ContentIdentity();
effectSource.Identity.SourceFilename = input.name;
//End of correction
EffectProcessor processor = new EffectProcessor();
compiledEffect = processor.Process(effectSource, context);
```